# Why can't the console in Xcode print my object's property using dot notation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, lldb

I have a UIButton which I've set the accessibilityLabel on. Why can't the console find the accessibility label property when I try to print it using dot notation?

```
(lldb) po self.closeButton.accessibilityLabel
error: property 'accessibilityLabel' not found on object of type 'UIButton *'
error: 1 errors parsing expression
(lldb) po [self.closeButton accessibilityLabel]
topsecretlabel
```

Comment: Property syntax decays into method calls.  The same is true of LLDB's view of protocols that declare properties.  It is not a property of the object, so much as it is a promise that there will be a setter and getter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`accessibilityLabel` is not a property of `UIButton`. It is a method defined by the *informal* `UIAccessibility` protocol that `UIButton` happens to respond to. `lldb` tends to be more strict about these things than clang is, and it is not strictly legal to refer to a non-property by dot-notation.

The fact that it's an informal protocol actually makes things much harder on lldb. You cannot easily determine that `UIButton` implements the protocol (it's technically an extension of `NSObject`). We don't use informal protocols as much anymore for that reason.

Comment: `accessibilityLabel ` is a property declared in the class category `NSObject (UIAccessibility)`. Why is it not legal to refer to that property by the dot-notation? - I made a small test with a property `myprop` defined in a class category `MyClass (MyCategory)`, and for that the dot notation worked in lldb.

Comment: Categories and informal protocols are different.  A category is bolted onto the classdef, but like I said, properties in protocols decay into setters and getters.  Or maybe it's a case of lldb not searching the inheritance tree.

Comment: I don't think you'd really want it to attach all the informal methods to every object, either. The auto-complete list would get kind of crazy. Especially on Mac, there have to be hundreds of methods that would be included. There are 64 informal protocols in 10.9. (There are only 9 in iOS, but the tools run on all the platforms.)

Comment: Not saying that they would never make it work, but I see why they didn't go heavily down that road (and the lack of new informal protocols makes it less likely they'd add even more special code that's just a convenience in the debugger).

Comment: Oops… miscounted. There are 102 informal NSObject protocols in 10.9 and 25 in iOS 7.1.

Answer (score 1):

One of the things you can specify as part of the declaration of ObjC properties is setters and getters that don't follow the normal naming convention.  So without knowing the details of the property declaration, lldb doesn't know how to turn the dot notation into the correct method call.  If it has debug information, it can do this job.  But we try not to guess about this sort of thing in the debugger.  So if we don't have debug info, you have to tell us what the setter is (by manually converting the . notation to the correct method call.)

Anyway, you do have access to the header file that declares accessibilityLabel property so this still should work correctly. Sadly, there is a bug in clang that it doesn't emit debug information for properties declared in categories on classes.  As it turns out, accessibilityLabel is defined in the UIAccessibility category on NSObject.  So it gets no debug information.  So you can't use dot notation on it.

Comment: It doesn't seem like it is just NSObject category properties that don't get debug info, for instance no debug info is generated for all the interesting UIViewGeometry properties on UIView, though the ones straight on UIView do get debug info.  And I didn't see this in some toy I made either.  I'd be interested to see Martin's example that did work...